# How to generate Token Authentication for for Already existing users table in my private database in Django REST API?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have table `users` in my private database with username, password, email, status, creation_date, updated_date,... etc. with some rows of data.

I want to generate Tokens for this users ?

So I want to use my private database users table instead of Django DB `auth_users` table for generations of tokens for username's present my private database.

```
  id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0=>active,1=>inactive,2=>delete',
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_sys_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_agency_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_adv_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_pub_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `is_bidder_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `template_id` int(11) DEFAULT -1,
  `camp_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campaign Listing Page Filters',
  `adv_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Advertiser Listing Page Filters',
  `agency_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Agency Listing Page Filters',
  `account_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Account Listing Page Filters',
  `user_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Listing Page Filters',
  `template_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Template Listing Page Filters',
  `connection_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `adgroup_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Adgroup Listing Page Filters',
  `dashboard_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_timezone` varchar(200) DEFAULT 'UTC' COMMENT 'User Default Timezone',
  `ad_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ads Listing Page Filters',
  `segment_list_filters` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Audience Segment Listing Page Filters',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: See how do I ask a good question? [ask]